# Mostrar ou esconder uma opção de gravidez, sempre que o usuário selecionar no cadastro que é do sexo feminino

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Como faço para que em uma página de cadastro de pacientes apareça ou esconda uma opção de dizer se o paciente é gestante ou não. A opção só apareceria se o usuário marcasse a opção de Feminino.

A imagem abaixo mostra uma previa da página de cadastro. A parte marcada em vermelho é a parte que eu quero que apareça apenas quando o sexo for feminino.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Utilize `ng-if` ou `ng-show` para controlar a exibição de conteúdo.

**`ng-if`** cria e destrói objetos no DOM.
**`ng-show`** apenas controla a visibilidade do objeto, preservando-o.

Exemplo a seguir:

```js
function SampleController($scope) {
  $scope.sexo = 'M';
}
```

```html
<html ng-app>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div ng-controller="SampleController">

      Sexo:
      <select name="sexoSelect" ng-model="sexo">
        <option value="M">Masculino</option>
        <option value="F">Feminino</option>
      </select>

      <div ng-if='sexo == "F"'>
        Gravidez: 
        <select name="gravSelect" ng-model="gravidez">
          <option value="S">Sim</option>
          <option value="N">Não</option>
        </select>
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar a opção ng-show ou ng-hide `<div ng-show="myValue"></div>`.

Na página a seguir tem um exemplo caso precise:
[AngularJS NgShow](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow)